# run multiple queries in array with multi_query

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have a text file that i opened it and converted it to object and i want when condition is true put the query statement in an array name autocharges and then foreach in array and run queries with multi_query . my problem is it doesn't insert two row in table and it just insert one row and runs query that relates to first line of my text file

```
$file = fopen(__DIR__.'/acf.txt', "r" );
while ( !feof( $file ) ) {
$content = json_decode(fgets( $file ));
        $convertedObjToArr = get_object_vars($content);
        $event_type = $convertedObjToArr['event-type'];
        $status = $convertedObjToArr['status'];
        $date = $convertedObjToArr['datetime'];
        if($status == '0' AND $event_type == '1.5'){
            $sql = " INSERT INTO auto_charge(phone,charged_at,created_at,updated_at) VALUES ('$content->msisdn','$date','$now','$now');";
            $autoCharges[ $content->sid ] .= $sql;
            $c++;
        }
}
foreach ( $autoCharges as $sid => $query ) {
    $result = $conn->multi_query( $query );
    $conn->close();
}
```

and this is my text:

```
{"sid":7790,"trans-id":"PROV_151678481611490383229","status":"0","base-price-point":"3000","msisdn":"989120572595","keyword":"","validity":1,"next_renewal_date":"2018-01-25 12:36:56.634","shortcode":"","billed-price-point":"3000","trans-status":0,"chargeCode":"MEHRENCMEHCLAS3000","datetime":"2018-01-24 12:37:07","event-type":"1.5","channel":"system"}
{"sid":4567,"trans-id":"PROV_151678481611490383229","status":"0","base-price-point":"3000","msisdn":"989107786574","keyword":"","validity":1,"next_renewal_date":"2018-01-25 12:36:56.634","shortcode":"","billed-price-point":"3000","trans-status":0,"chargeCode":"MEHRENCMEHCLAS3000","datetime":"2018-01-24 12:37:07","event-type":"1.5","channel":"system"}
```

Comment: Why multi_query? I see only one query here.

Comment: @Strawberry i have 2 queries

Comment: Surely you have one query, inserting two rows. !?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry it reads json file and i have 2 event_type with 1.5 value and code snippet in while so two query adds to array

Comment: I don't understand that sentence

Comment: @Strawberry you have to print_r($autoCharges) before second foreach and you will see that i have 2 queries in my arra